# SQL Table Data Source

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I've been tasked with creating a data dictionary for a DB that has 90 tables. Is there any way to identify by which procedure/task/job a table is populated? I need to source the data in each of the tables and I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
-T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for which stored procedures use a given table with something like:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) FROM SYSCOMMENTS WHERE text LIKE '%table_name%'
```

You'll then have to manually examine and analyse the code within those SPs to see what it actually does with that table. I expect you'll need to manually eyeball any SQL Agent tasks and SSIS packages you may have as well. This kind of work tends to be hard graft - there aren't many shortcuts to simply grinding over all the code by hand.